# How do I group list of numbers using some range in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list of numbers and I want to group them based on some range. Let's say 1000. Instead of grouping every consecutive number, I want to group all numbers that are within range of 1000 of one another.

For example,

```
Data=[900,1050,1900,2100,9000,10000]
```

The output which I require is:

```
[(900,1050,1900),(1900,2100),(9000,10000)]
```

Comment: This seems reasonably straightforward to do with a loop.  Did something go wrong when you tried that we could help you with?

Comment: I was using simple loop like this:                                                                                                              groups = [[data[0]]]
    for x in data[1:]:
        if abs(x - groups[-1][-1]) <= 1000:
            groups[-1].append(x)
        else:
            groups.append([x])
    return groups                                                                                                   This loop resulted in the grouping like this: [900, 1050, 1900, 2100],  [9000, 10000]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear to me how you want to handle the edge cases, but you should be able to handle whatever you want with a fairly naive approach, such as

```
def group(l, group_range):
    groups = []
    this_group = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(l):
        a = l[i]
        if len(this_group) == 0:
            if i == len(l) - 1:
                break
            this_group_start = a
        if a <= this_group_start + group_range:
            this_group.append(a)
        if a < this_group_start + group_range:
            i += 1
        else:
            groups.append(this_group)
            this_group = []
    groups.append(this_group)
    return [tuple(g) for g in groups if len(g) != 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code finds the required output and returns each range as an entry into a Python list.

```
import numpy

data=numpy.array([-5600, 900,2400,1050,1900,2100,9000,10000])
data_max = numpy.max(data)
data_min = numpy.min(data)

num_thousands = numpy.floor(data_min/1000)
start_value  = num_thousands*1000

num_thousands = numpy.floor(data_max/1000)
end_value  = num_thousands*1000
num_thousands = (end_value - start_value)/1000
msg = ''
loop_range_start = start_value
loop_range_end = start_value + 1000

num = 0

a = []
for k in numpy.arange(num_thousands):
    if(k==num_thousands-1):
        temp = numpy.logical_and(data>=loop_range_start, data<=loop_range_end)
    else:
        temp = numpy.logical_and(data>=loop_range_start, data<loop_range_end)
    vals = data[temp]
    if(vals.shape[0] != 0):
        vals = numpy.sort(vals)
        a.append(vals.tolist())
        num = num + 1
    loop_range_start = loop_range_start + 1000
    loop_range_end = loop_range_end + 1000

print('There are ', num, ' ranges.')
print(a)
```